# Passing values after clicking on the Button - React Native

Tags: react-native, button, navigation, render

How can I pass all values inside Render() method after I click on the button Send? Inside this Render() method I return some Flatlists, Views, Signature, etc. So, is it possible to pass all of these values to another page only by a click of a button.

Please let me know if you dont have the question clear so I can add some more explanation.

See below for the code (Edited).

I appreciate any suggestion or help!

EDIT:

```
    renderTextandInputs = (obje) => {
    var keyvalue_to_json = JSON.parse(obje.keyValues);
    var foundTextFields = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < keyvalue_to_json.length; i++) {
      if (keyvalue_to_json[i].type === 'textfield') {
        foundTextFields.push(<TextInput style={{ borderWidth: 1, flex: 1, alignItems: 'flex-start' }}>{keyvalue_to_json[i].placeholderText}</TextInput>)
      }
    }
    return (
      <View>
        <ScrollView>
          <ListItem
            title={obje.name}
            subtitle={obje.description}
          />

        </ScrollView>
        <View >
          {foundTextFields}
        </View>
      </View>

    )
  }


  render() {

    const obj = this.props.navigation.state.params.item;
    var propsArray = [];
    const itemArray = Object.assign(obj)
    propsArray.push(itemArray)

    keyExtractor = (item, index) => {
      return index.toString();
    }

    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <FlatList
            key={this.keyExtractor}
            data={propsArray}
            renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderTextandInputs(item)}
          />
        </View>    
        <View >
          {this.state.signature ? (
            <Image
              resizeMode={"contain"}
              source={{ uri: this.state.signature }}
            />
          ) : null}
        </View>

        <Modal isVisible={this.state.isModalVisible}
          onBackdropPress={() => this.setState({ isModalVisible: false })}
        >       
          <Signature
            width="100"
            onOK={this.handleSignature}
            descriptionText="Sign"
            clearText="Clear"
            confirmText="Save"
            webStyle={style}
          />
        </Modal>

        <View>
          <Button title="SIGN" onPress={this._toggleModal} />
        </View>

        <View>
          <Button title="Send" onPress={this._onSendDoc} />
        </View>

      </View>
    );
  }

_onSendDoc = (item) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail', { item: item })
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the button "Send" you mentioned? What have you tried so far that allows a click of button to send the data to the next page? That should be simple, just pass the data as props to the next component/page

Comment: @TyroHunter I havent even tried. I know I cant have parameters in Render() so what parameters do I need in the button : onPress={() => this.onPressItem( )}

Answer (score 1):

if you check here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist you can render a button per flatlist item like this:

**EDIT**

```
_onSendAll = () => {
  const obj = this.props.navigation.state.params.item;
  var propsArray = [];
  const itemArray = Object.assign(obj)
  propsArray.push(itemArray)

  this.props.navigation.navigate("Detail", { allData: propsArray });
};


_onSendDoc = item => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate("Detail", { item: item });
};

render() {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={[{title: 'Title Text', key: 'item1'}]}
      renderItem={({item}) => (
        <TouchableHighlight
          onPress={() => this._onSendDoc(item)}
          <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
            <Text>{item.title}</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      )}
    />
  )
```

On each button clicked, the item data passed will be logged.

Comment: I have edited my code, can you check and let me know how would you pass all those data? I know how to pas for ex. data of a ListItem, but here I have ListItem which renders some texts , input fields, and I have a signature as image.

Comment: seems a lot of parses happening, can you send a sample value for `obje.keyValues`?

Comment: thats because keyValues are a string so I had to parse them, here is the log output sample before parsing: '[ { "type": "textfield", "placeholderText" : "Enter your full name", "title" : "Name" }]'

Comment: And the thing is that I dont want to pass these data to another screen, but to post them using fetch() to a server.

Comment: I edited my answer, and provided two answers because I'm not sure what you need. _onSendAll has access to props so you can simply pass all the data to next screen. On the other hand, Use _onSendDoc to only pass 1 item, so pass a function instead, hence `() => this._onSendDoc(item)`. And not `onPress={this._onSendDoc}` when no data was fed to _onSendDoc. Let me know if this helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I include two properties here ("Detail", { allData: propsArray }). I want to pass the signature image as well.

Comment: And by the way, I dont think your code is passing the input values of the textinputs.

Comment: well that's an object so simply add more property like this: `{ allData: propsArray, 2ndData: 123, anotherData: someArray }`

Comment: I don't have the code about text inputs. Do you want to store input values the user types on your text input? But you don't have that here

Comment: Yes I want to store input values the user types. I do have, thats what  {foundTextFields} is displaying

Comment: Read this, you'll figure out what I mean. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput. I mean also try this until you'll be able to store what the user types in this.state

Comment: alright I will check that but what about the signature image? Thats not in Flatlist, how can I pass that too at the same time?

Comment: you have this `<Image
              resizeMode={"contain"}
              source={{ uri: this.state.signature }}
            />` does it not work?